# how to do pdf digital signaturein j2ee applications

Tags: java, pdf, jakarta-ee, digital-signature

any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html) is an extensive tutorial on how to do this with [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). I can guarantee it works, I've used it.